# how to change a UILabel of a UIViewController from another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

i have a two UIViewController named FirstUIViewController and SecondUIViewController and i want to change the text of a UILabel on the SecondtUIViewController from the FirstUIViewController when i pressed the button from the FirstUIviewController. i don't know how to do it i am new to objective-c and ios development.

here is what i currently have

**FirstUIViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstUIViewController

IBAction Button1:(id)sender;
@end
```

**FirstUIViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation FirstUIViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewdidload {
//some codes here.
}
```

**SecondUIViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondUIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

@end
```

**SecondUIViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondUIViewController.h"

@implementation FirstUIViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewdidload {
//some codes here.
}
```

Comment: Do they have a relation? Are you using push to navigate to SecondUIViewController?

Comment: im not using push to navigate to the seconduiviewcontroller but the seconduiviewcontroller is a subview of a UIView and the UIView is presented on the FirstUIViewController (the Main/root UIViewController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy method is store the property in the AppDelegate and set/get it there.

In `AppDelegate.h`  `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *transferString;`
In `AppDelegate.m`  `@synthesize transferString`

In both your first and second v`iewcontrollers.m` import `"AppDelegate.h"`
create a property for it  `@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;`

in the viewcontrollers `viewDidLoad` set it   `self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

then just get or set the string value in the `appDelegate` in your viewcontrollers

to set it: `self.appDelegate.transferString = aString;`
to get it:  `NSString *theString = self.appDelegate.transferString;`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare a delegate protocol for your class. An example of a delegate protocol and interface for class `Foo` might look like this:

```
@class Foo;
@protocol FooDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (BOOL)foo:(Foo *)foo willDoSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)flag;
- (void)foo:(Foo *)foo didDoSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)flag;
@end

@interface Foo : NSObject {
     NSString *bar;
     id <FooDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FooDelegate> delegate;

- (void)changeLabelText;

@end
```

Don't forget to synthesize your properties in the `@implementation`.

The last step is for a `Foo` object to be instantiated in the class that conforms to `FooDelegate`, and for this `Foo` object to have its delegate property set:

```
Foo *obj = [[Foo alloc] init];
[obj setDelegate:self];
```

Now, your class is prepared to receive messages from `Foo` objects that have their delegates set correctly.

Comment: hi i tried to implement your solution but i couldn't get it to worked can you provide a step by step procedure? thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using storyboard you just have to create an instance of the second screen and then you can refer to the secondviewcontroller properties.

on the .h file of the first screen:
creating an instance of the secondviewpage

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)SecondViewController *detailcontroller;
```

on the .m file of the first view (when you want to load the page).

```
self.detailcontroller = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

self.detailcontroller.label
```

//str as some nsstring variable in the secondViewController

now you cant access the "SecondViewController" from the first view by the dot notation

hope i helped you.

idan

Comment: hi idan i tried you solution.. it worked in the viewdidload function on the FirstUIViewController, but when i put it in other function that i created it didn't worked im sure na the function is being called.

Comment: yeah thats what i thought too. but its not. im using xcode5 any ideas??